# mmap PCIe BAR, return -EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Tags: linux-kernel, mmap, pci-e

On a Ubuntu platform, when execute it with root, it always returns `-EPERM Operation not permitted`, I don't know which configuration should I change. The region info of the PCIe:

```
  Region 0: Memory at 3f900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Region 0: Memory at 3f904000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable)
```

The code is as following.

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd;
    void *base;
    int bar_size = 16384;
    char path[256];

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <pci-device-id>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "/sys/bus/pci/devices/%s/resource0", argv[1]);

    fd = open(path, O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }

    base = mmap(NULL, bar_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (base == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("Error mapping BAR");
        close(fd);
        return 1;
```

I changed the parameter MPA_SHARED to MAP_PRIVATE, also returns -EPERM. I check the Linux kernel configuration: `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=y`, but another machine with same configuration, can be mapped successfully.

Comment: By any chance, do you have SELinux configured on your machine?

Comment: Thank you very much for your info, I have checked that: SELinux status:                 disabled.

Comment: Files in /sys are not actual files that can be mapped to memory.

Comment: After change the BIOS configuration to secure boot disabled, it can be mapped successfully.

Comment: Side note: Why not use `libpci` for your purposes?

Comment: have you set the kernel parameter `CONFIG_IO_STRICT_DEVMEM=n`?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I am familiar with to utilize a PCI device from user-space is to bind the PCI device to the `uio_pci_generic` driver and use the facilities of this driver to map the BARs. That's what SPDK does for NVMe devices for example. You can look it for for full details on this is done.